# ¿Por qué corre tan lento mi script Python con en Windows cuando uso pySerial?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyserial

Tengo un programa que lee el puerto serial para mi caso com3
pero al correrlo en Windows se ralentiza y se hace muy lento. Lo he corrido en Mac y corre mucho mejor, pero aun así,  es tan rapido como deberia.
No tiene cálculos complicados, esta corriendo pero aun no es como debería. Estoy trabajando con python 3.7, corriendo en una laptop i7 de 2.8Ghz con win10 de 32 bits y 16 Gb de Ram  disco duro mSATA de 220 GB (estado solido).

El otro problema que tengo, es que no arranca si no está conectado el puerto serie.

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
import json
import serial

a="a"

ser=serial.Serial("COM3",115200)  #tty.usbmodemFD111  tty.usbmodemFA131
#ser=serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodemFD111',115200)  #tty.usbmodemFD111  tty.usbmodemFA131
polea = 2/1200

def cero ():

    valor=messagebox.askokcancel("Salir", "Desea Resetear el contador??")
    if valor == True:


            codificado = a.encode("utf8")
            ser.write(codificado)

def infoAdicional():
    messagebox.showinfo("Procesador de Edgar", "Procesador de Informacion V 2019" )

def avisoLicencia():
    messagebox.showwarning("'Licencia'", "Producto Bajo Licencia EOSC  V 2019" )

def salirAplicaion():

    valor=messagebox.askokcancel("Salir?", "Desea salir de la aplicacion??")

    #if valor=="yes":
    if valor==True:
        root.destroy() #cierra la ventana  y termina el porograma

def cerrarDocumento():
        valor=messagebox.askretrycancel("Reinterntar", "No es posible cerrar. Documentoi Bloqueado")
        if valor==True:
                root.destroy() #cierra la ventana  y termina el porograma


def loop():
    lector  =  ser.readline() # leo el puerto serial ser=serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodemFA131',115200)
    #time.sleep(0.1)
    try:
        json_data = json.loads(lector)
        leo = json_data
        #enco = leo/2
        valor = round((polea*leo),1)

        var.set(valor)
        root.after(1,loop)
    except ValueError:
        print('NO se puede leer puerto: %s', lector)


def destroy():
    ser.close()


root= tk.Tk() #Tk() #es una ventana

#a5 = PhotoImage(file="g1.png")
root.title("Monitor  V0.0")  #win.title("Ardiotech Raspberry Pi Version 2.0")
root.geometry("1200x600+100+100") # de aqui se cambia el tamaño de la ventana
root.resizable(width=True, height=True)
root.configure(bg='black')
root.iconbitmap(default='favicons.ico')
#var=tk.StringVar()

var=tk.IntVar()


#*****************************


barraMenu=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=barraMenu,width=200,height=800)


archivoMenu=Menu(barraMenu,tearoff=0)

#agregar elementos de menus
archivoMenu.add_command(label="Nuevo")
archivoMenu.add_command(label="Guardar")
archivoMenu.add_command(label="Guardar Como")
archivoMenu.add_separator() #dibuja separador
archivoMenu.add_command(label="Cerrar",command=cerrarDocumento)
archivoMenu.add_command(label="Salir",command=salirAplicaion)


archivoEdicion=Menu(barraMenu,tearoff=0)
archivoEdicion.add_command(label="Copiar")
archivoEdicion.add_command(label="Cortar")
archivoEdicion.add_command(label="Pegar")

archivoHerramientas=Menu(barraMenu,tearoff=0)
archivoHerramientas.add_command(label="Unidades de Medida")

archivoAyuda=Menu(barraMenu,tearoff=0)
archivoAyuda.add_command(label="Licencia",command=avisoLicencia)
archivoAyuda.add_command(label="Acerca de......", command=infoAdicional)



#menus
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Archivo",menu=archivoMenu)

barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Edicion",menu=archivoEdicion)

barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Herramientas",menu=archivoHerramientas)

barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Ayuda",menu=archivoAyuda)

        #******agrega etiqueta de texto
lblUsuario = Label(text="Depth:", font=("Arial",50)).place(x=10,y=120)
lblUsuario = Label(text="fts", font=("Arial",42)).place(x=1370,y=170)
        #entradaU=StringVar() # es una variable de clase string
Helvfont=font.Font(family="Helvetica",size=192, weight="bold")

        #txtUsuario=Entry(root,textvariable=entradaU).place(x=95,y=705)
salida = tk.Label(root,bg="green",textvariable=var,font=Helvfont,bd=7,relief=FLAT,width=6).place(x=250,y=95) #,padx=15,pady=105)
#ser.close()
        #salida.pack()
boton = Button(root, text = "Poner a Cero '0' - ",command = cero).place(x=842,y=350)

loop()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema puede estar en la funcion `readline()` ya que según la [documentacion](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html#readline) se debe especificar un timeout al crear el objeto serial para que esta función no sea bloqueante. El objeto deberia crearse así:

```
ser=serial.Serial("COM3",115200, timeout=0.5) # timeout 0.5 segundos
```

Los posibles valores para timeout son:

- **timeout = None:** Espera siempre o hasta que se reciban los bytes indicados
- **timeout = 0:** No bloquea, retorna inmediatamente con 0 o más bytes, máximo el numero d ebytes indicados
- **timeout = x:** retorna inmediatamente el numero de bytes requeridos o por el contrario espera x segundos (como float) y retorna los bytes recibidos hasta ese momento

En cuanto a esto:

> el otro problema que tengo es que no arranca si no esta conectado el puerto serie.

supongo que si no está conectado, la creación del objeto arrojará una excepción, haciendo que el programa aborte. Si quisieras que el programa funcione independiente de la conexión, deberias incluir una especie de monitor que verifique que hay un dispositivo antes de leer y escribir, y que intente conectarse en caso que no exista. Todo esto manejando las excepciones.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando un script python consume muchos recursos  lo mejor es ponerle un un breve descanso.En el caso de PySerial para reducir el uso de la CPU, podrías agregar una pequeña demora, usando time.sleep (0.01). Esto reducirá la carga de la CPU, pero aumentará la performance ya que los buffers recopilaran los datos hasta que los lea todos.Lo puedes poner después de la lectura:

```
ser=serial.Serial("COM3",115200)
time.sleep (0.1) # Prueba con diferentes valores (0.01 a 0.1)


lector  =  ser.readline()
time.sleep (0.1) # Lo tienes comentado prueba también con este time.sleep
```

Lo que no entiendo bien en este script es el uso de los dos loops; loop() y root.mainloop() pero me imagino que eso debe estar correcto.